# making y-axis labels bold in ggplot (x-axis is set bold but y-axis label doesn't change)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to set axis labels and ticks bold in ggplot but y-axis labels is not setting to bold. Please suggest what I should add to the script. Below is a reproducible example. I do need 'atop' command to set y-axis labels string as in the example below.

Thanks in advance.

```
library(ggplot2)

chart <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = table, fill = clarity)) +

geom_histogram() +

  scale_x_continuous('Month') + 

 scale_y_continuous(expression(atop('ET (W'~m^-2~')')))

chart<-chart+theme(axis.title.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=20,face="bold"),
     axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=20,face="bold"),
     axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=20,face="bold"),  
     axis.title.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=20,face="bold"))  

print(chart)
```

Comment: This works for me. The answer might lie in the specific capabilities of your OS (i.e. typefaces installed, etc.). The output of `sessionInfo()` would be a start.

Comment: I am using: R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

Comment: Not in the comments! In your question!

Comment: typing session info on output console gives me the R version and Platform as posted in prev. comment. Additionally  attached base packages info displays:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3
 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-1   dichromat_2.0-0   digest_0.6.3   grid_2.15.2       
 [5] gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.1       MASS_7.3-22  munsell_0.4       
 [9] plyr_1.8           proto_0.3-10 RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.2    
[13] scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2

Comment: You might find an answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803727/ggplot-scale-x-continuous-with-symbol-make-bold

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and got this to work:

```
ylab(expression(atop(bold('ET (W'~m^-2~')'), paste(bold('something else'[here])))))
```

Hope that helps.