# ggplot2 axis text formatting won't work with exponents

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, plotmath

It is easy enough to change the axis text of a ggplot to some sort of expression (in this case 10^.x). However, when the text is transformed, it loses bold formatting.

I was wondering if there was a way to retain bold formatting but also have the exponent labelling shown below.

```
library(ggplot2)

xxx <- data.frame(
  x = c(-5, -4, -3),
  y = c(1, 1, 1)
)

ggplot(xxx, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(label = scales::label_math(expr = 10^.x)) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own problem just after posting this. I adapted the `make_labels` function from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803727/ggplot-scale-x-continuous-with-symbol-make-bold).

The trick is to paste the axis numbers as text and then use bold (or italic or whatever) within an expression to control the formatting.

```
library(ggplot2)

xxx <- data.frame(
  x = c(-5, -4, -3),
  y = c(1, 1, 1)
)

exp_bold <- function(lab) {
  do.call(
    expression,
    lapply(paste(lab), function(x) bquote(bold("10"^.(x))))
  )
}

ggplot(xxx, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(label = exp_bold) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>