# How to make scale_y_log10 with labels of trans_format in bold?

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, axis, typography

Based on the answers I read on this question: [Bold axis label in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67414487/bold-axis-label-in-ggplot)
I still have the output with y axis labelled bold but the exponents not math formated? How can I modify this code  to be bold:

```
scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10",function(x) 10^x),  
              labels = trans_format("log10",math_format(10^.x)),                 
              limits=c(0.00005,5))+ #2.5
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide a reproducable example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If you use `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=10, face="bold", color = "black"))`, the exponents in the y-axis-labels are in-fact bold, though they are much smaller, they appear to be not.